# Двоичный код из String в int

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перенести число из String в int, которое представляет из себя двоичный код, при этом **не используя Integer.parseInt(String, int)**.
Сама проблема кроется в том, что у меня не получается *к переменной-результату прибавить 0b*, чтобы характеризовать int как бинарный код.

```
char[] array = String.toCharArray();           // Копирую данные из строки в массив char           
int result = 0;                                // Переменная с результатом
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++) {    // Проход по массиву и забирание цифр
int digit = array[i] - '0';
result += digit;
if(array.length-1!=array[i]){
result *= 10;
```

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что должно в итоге получиться, как и то, зачем вам к результату прибавлять 0b?

Comment: int result  = 0b+"числа из массива"

Comment: int не может содержать в себе b. И это 0b появляется только при выводе числа на экран, именно для того, чтобы показать, что этот формат - двоичный. А все числа в памяти уже в двоичном формате. И то, что вы делаете в своем коде - это совсем не перевод в двоичный код, а непонятно что. Ничего в двоичный код переводить не надо, оно уже в двоичном коде.

Comment: Я и спрашиваю как это сделать, вы, если не знаете, как это сделать, пожалуйста не отвечайте

Comment: Я вам уже ответил. Вы не сможете сделать то, что вам хочется, потому что а) это не имеет смысла и невозможно, б) вы не понимаете разницы между выводом и хранением, и в) не желаете эту разницу понять. Вы даже не дочитали мой предыдущий комментарий до конца. Вы можете сделать двоичное представление числа с 0b в начале, но это будет не int, а строка.

Comment: Ваша проблема выглядит примерно так: "как мне написать китайское слово 新年 но только русскими буквами и по-английски?" Ответ: никак.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорят что нельзя использовать Integer.ParseInt это не значит, что вы не можете посмотреть как он устроен в пакете java.lang, и сделать тоже самое. Зачем правда, не знаю.

```
    int start = -200;
    String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(start);
    System.out.println(bits);
    int result=0;
    int digit;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bits.length();i++){
        digit = Character.digit(bits.charAt(i),2);
        result*=2;
        result-=digit;
    }

    System.out.println(start < 0 ? result = result-result*2 : Math.abs(result));
```

Comment: вы не понимаете, товарищ хочет в result добавить "0b". А не вывести число в двоичном виде.

Comment: @Эникейщик блин я кажется понял что он хочет, сейчас исправлю )

Comment: и не упускайте из виду, что result должно быть int ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик наверно так...